# Django - post InMemoryUploadedFile to external REST api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In the Django Rest Framework I would like to post a file, received as an `InMemoryUploadedFile`, to a different server as soon as it is received.

It sounds simple, but the `request.post()` function does not seem to properly send over such a file :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    # <QueryDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: myfile.pdf (application/pdf)>]}>
    endpoint = OTHER_API_URL + "/endpoint"
    r = requests.post(endpoint, files=data)
```

My other server receives the request (through flask) with the name of the file, but not the content:

```
@app.route("/endpoint", methods=["POST"])
def endpoint():
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        # I removed the many checks to simplify the code
        file = flask.request.files['file']
        path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, file.filename)
        file.save(path)        

        print(file) #<FileStorage: u'file.pdf' (None)>
        print(os.path.getsize(path)) #0

        return [{"response":"ok"}]
```

When posting a file directly to that api in form-data with postman, It works as expected:

```
        print(file) # <FileStorage: u'file.pdf' ('application/pdf')>
        print(os.path.getsize(path)) #8541
```

Any help on how to fix this, i.e. transform the `InMemoryUploadedFile` type in something a normal REST api can understand? Or maybe just adding the right headers?

Comment: Can you include the relevant Flask view, to see how the files are handled on the receiving end?

Comment: it contains self.request.FILES

Comment: @kristaps I edited the question with the details.

Comment: Are there any proxies between the two servers, something that could alter the request to the Flask server?

Comment: No, the two servers are two separate docker containers

Comment: The only (very inefficient) way I manage to make it work is: 
1. save the file on the drive of the first server
2. open it again with `open(path, 'rb')` 
3. make the post request to the second server
4. delete the file from my first server

Answer (score 7):

I had to figure this issue out passing an uploaded file from a Django front end website to a Django backend API in Python 3. The InMemoryUploadedFile's actual file data can be accessed via the object's .file property's .getvalue() method.

```
        path="path/to/api"
        in_memory_uploaded_file = request.FILES['my_file']
        io_file = in_memory_uploaded_file.file
        file_value = io_file.getvalue()
        files = {'my_file': file_value}
        make_http_request(path, files=files)
```

and can be shortened

```
        file = request.FILES['my_file'].file.getvalue()
        files = {'my_file': file}
```

Before this, trying to send InMemoryUploadFile objects, the file property, or the result of the read() method all proved to send a blank/empty file by the time it got to the API.

Comment: i tried the following code. but doesn't work for me.

Comment: `view.py-
  kyc_file = request.FILES['kyc_doc'].file.getvalue()
  files = {"kyc_doc":kyc_file}
  resp = accService.publishKY(data,files)
--------
Service.py -- 
def publishKY(self,data,files):
 curl = CurlWrapper()
 response_kcloud = curl.post(endpoint,data,{ "api-key":acc.api_key,"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"},files)
------
class CurlWrapper():
def post(self,url,data,headers,ufile=None):
  if ufile is None:
 return requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
   else:
return requests.post(url, data=data, headers=curlheaders,files=ufile)`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the same case.
My working solution

```
    headers = {
        "Host": API_HOST,
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
    }

    try:
        data = json_request = request.POST['json_request'].strip()
        data = json.loads(data) # important!
    except:
        raise Http404

    try:
        in_memory_uploaded_file = request.FILES['file'].file.getvalue() 
        files = {'photo': in_memory_uploaded_file} # important!
    except:
        files = {}

    if USE_HTTPS:
        API_HOST = f'https://{API_HOST}'
    else:
        API_HOST = f'http://{API_HOST}'

    if authorization_key and len(authorization_key) > 0:
        response = requests.post(f'{API_HOST}/api/json/?authorization_key={authorization_key}', headers=headers, data=data, files=files)
    else:    
        response = requests.post(f'{API_HOST}/api/json/', headers=headers, data=data)

    json_response = json.dumps(response.json())
```

Comment: Hi! This gives me ```ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.```